# MySQL: How to get a count of events occurred within a span of 24 hrs using ONLY COUNT() and WITHOUT using WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, count

This is my scenario:

I am collecting IP addresses of clients pinging my server and also the time of ping in MySQL.

```
Columns:
IP_address, Time_of_Ping(date - hr - min - sec)
```

At any given point of time, I want to know how many clients have been communicated with my server in the last 24 hrs.

Please note: I know this can be done with a simple select statement with where clause.

*But why I am posting this in the forum just to know: can this be done with just count() I mean just writing some condition within count() and without using where clause?*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take advantage of MySQL treating boolean expressions as either 1 or 0 in a numeric context and use `SUM`:

```
SELECT SUM(Time_of_Ping > NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select count(*) as num_pings, count(distinct ip_address) as num_ips
from t
where time_of_ping > now() - interval 24 hour;
```

Note that `count(*)` is the number of pings.  `count(distinct)` is the number of different ip address, which is what I think you really want.

Comment: Thanks for your response, appreciate! But what I wrote is I already know how to get count using WHERE clause. What I want is if writing some condition inside count() and WITHOUT using WHILE I can get the count in 1 liner query

Answer (score 0):

I got the expected query and it is working fine:

```
select count(ping_time > datetime('now', '-24 hours')) from testTable
```